# Configure ADFS with Windows Authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth, kerberos, windows-authentication

I created an integration of an existing product that shows reports in web, comparable to Reporting Services. This product needs Windows Authentication or Kerberos/ asp.net impersonation to access certain resources (relational databases) and for some (weird) DCOM configuration.

When configuring Sharepoint to use ADFS (claims-based authentication) it seems I have to configure anonymous authentication, what means that there is no impersonation available.

- Is there any possibility to configure the web service with windows authentication while using ADFS?
- Is that the right way or should I try to do it like described here "To temporarily impersonate the authenticated user": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx?

Anyone experience with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Using SAML Claims, SharePoint, WCF, Claims to Windows Token Service and Constrained Delegation to Access SQL Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2011/08/07/using-saml-claims-sharepoint-wcf-claims-to-windows-token-service-and-constrained-delegation-to-access-sql-server.aspx) or look through articles in the blog. They might give you a clue